# PySide2 cannot be installed on RPI 4B

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyside2

I am having an issue to install PySide2 on my RPI 4B.
I have been trying for several hours on two different RPIs and two different RPI images.
I have tried with the 32-bit and 64-bit rasbian OS directly from the RPI OS Imager (march 2022).
I have tried on python version 3.8 and 3.9, and I have checked i am working on the correct version with python -V each time.

I have clean installed them, done all updates, run sudo apt-get upgrade and tried multiple things.

When i try the following:

```
pip install PySide2
```

or

```
pip3 install PySide2
```

I get the following error:
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyside2
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyside2

On other forums, i have seen that i should try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyside2.qt3dcore python3-pyside2.qt3dinput python3-pyside2.qt3dlogic python3-pyside2.qt3drender python3-pyside2.qtcharts python3-pyside2.qtconcurrent python3-pyside2.qtcore python3-pyside2.qtgui python3-pyside2.qthelp python3-pyside2.qtlocation python3-pyside2.qtmultimedia python3-pyside2.qtmultimediawidgets python3-pyside2.qtnetwork python3-pyside2.qtopengl python3-pyside2.qtpositioning python3-pyside2.qtprintsupport python3-pyside2.qtqml python3-pyside2.qtquick python3-pyside2.qtquickwidgets python3-pyside2.qtscript python3-pyside2.qtscripttools python3-pyside2.qtsensors python3-pyside2.qtsql python3-pyside2.qtsvg python3-pyside2.qttest python3-pyside2.qttexttospeech python3-pyside2.qtuitools python3-pyside2.qtwebchannel python3-pyside2.qtwebsockets python3-pyside2.qtwidgets python3-pyside2.qtx11extras python3-pyside2.qtxml python3-pyside2.qtxmlpatterns python3-pyside2uic
```

However, this returns me with the error message:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-pyside2uic

If I delete the python3-pyside2uic, from the sudo command, it will run, but when I try to open my application, it opens a wheel window with no graphics (blank window) and gives an error message. This is clear as it needs the uic to run the window, but at least the rest kinda works?

I have tried to install PYQT5 to see if the PySide would be in that, so I have tried to install PYQT5 and PYQT5-tools which has worked, but not in getting my program to work.

I am running out of ideas of what to try. If I try to do it on my venv on my PC, the pyside2 is installed.

Any ideas for what I can try to do so that it can run on the RPI 4b?

Comment: same problem here, keeping the faith